Basic page transition with BarbaJS and AnimeJs
I'm testing BarbaJS with AnimeJS.
On the BarbaJs docs, there is an example of a basic transition made with GSAP, but since I'm using AnimeJS on my test page, I edited it to create a basic AnimeJS animation.
The enter animation works while the leave doesn't (it looks ignored by JS). Then, if I run the BarbaJS and GSAP example from their docs, it works great.
The HTML structure is the same as the one used on the BarbaJS docs, I only changed the namespace on the two pages and added different content inside the container to spot the changes while transitioning between the two pages.
This is the GSAP code from the BarbaJS docs:
barba.init({
      transitions: [{
            name: 'default-transition',
            leave(data) {
                  // create your stunning leave animation here
                  return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
                        opacity: 0
                  });
            },
            enter(data) {
                  // create your amazing enter animation here
                  return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
                        opacity: 0
                  });
            }
      }]
});

This is the one I edited for AnimeJS:
barba.init({
      transitions: [{
            name: 'default-transition',
            leave(data) {
                  // create your stunning leave animation here
                  return anime({
                        targets: data.current.container,
                        opacity: 0,
                        duration: 200,
                        translateY: 20,
                        easing: "linear"
                  });
            },
            enter(data) {
                  // create your amazing enter animation here
                  return anime({
                        targets: data.next.container,
                        opacity: 0,
                        duration: 200,
                        translateY: 20,
                        easing: "linear"
                  });
            }
      }]
});

